# Error when executing the application in android with setOnClickListener Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to create a global variable and then make a `R.id.omitir_swipe` and it doesn't work either, it doesn't give me errors in the compilation but when executing on my cell phone or in the emulator the app stops working I attach the image:

[image]

Maybe it is not the correct function that it should be in, if so tell me, or if there is a better way to do that setOnclickListener, also mention that `omit_swipe` is not a variable, but rather it is an id of a textView.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        bg = findViewById(R.id.bg_snow_splash)
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo_splash)
        penguin = findViewById(R.id.penguin_splash)

        val viewPager : ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.swipe_screen)
        pagerAdapter = ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.swipe_screen_anim)
        viewPager.startAnimation(anim)
        bg_snow_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1600f)
        }
        logo_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1400f)
        }
        penguin_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(1400f)
        }

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            var sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            var isFirstTime : Boolean = sharedPref.getBoolean("firstTime", true)
            if(isFirstTime)
            {
                var editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
                editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false)
                editor.commit()
            }
            else
            {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Intento con exito")
                }
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }, 5000)

        omitir_swipe.setOnClickListener{
           val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "xd")
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
```

Also mention that the TextView omit is located in 3 different fragments but the 3 with the id omitir_swipe

Logcat:
[image]

activity_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash.SplashActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_snow_splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_snow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_splash"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/penguin_splash"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.391"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo_splash"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/party_penguin"
        />

    <com.cuberto.liquid_swipe.LiquidPager
        android:id="@+id/swipe_screen"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What does logcat show?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I don't know what logcat is if you told me where it is located I would tell you what it says

Comment: Tell them that I just added a detail that I overlooked

Comment: if you are using Android Studio its located at thr bottom left part, you can scroll to see any exception that may have occured during the execution.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu TAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.yr.iolite, PID: 9813
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I'm going to edit the question and add it there, so it will be better because it doesn't let me put so many characters in the comment

Comment: You're calling setOnClickListener on null at line number 83

Comment: @AnimeshSahu findViewById<TextView>(R.id.omitir_swipe).setOnClickListener{ --> is this line, no matter how to write the code at the end it always tells me that

Comment: Could it be that it is because it is in 3 fragments, that is, 3 different layouts?

Comment: Is the view omitir_swipe placed on activity_splash layout?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu in the ViewPager you can see that's where I make the 3 fragments show the SplashActivity

Comment: @PxnditxYR did you manage to solve this? If not, could you please post the code of your `activity_splash.xml`

Comment: @Rey I have not solved it yet, I will edit the question there I will upload activity_splash.xml

Comment: @PxnditxYR so, judging by your `splash_activity.xml` I don't see `omitir_swipe` anywhere

Comment: @Rey That is why I tell you that it is in 3 different fragments that are shown in the com.cuberto.liquid_swipe.LiquidPager tag

Comment: @PxnditxYR well, you can't reference the `id` that is not present in the layout that you're inflating. So you need to figure out a different way to handle whatever you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
omitir_swipe= findViewById(R.id.omitir_swipe)
```

Comment: Error Smart cast to 'TextView!' is impossible, because 'omitir_swipe' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time, and ADD explicit this, but if I add this it doesn't give

Comment: @PxnditxYR just add the `TextView` type to your `omitir_swipe` variable then

Comment: I did the same var omitir_swipe : TextView = findBy... etc

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.omiti_swipe).setOnClickListener{
       val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "xd")
        }
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Not enough information to infer type variable T Error

Comment: I am using a TextView not a button compiles fine but still with the same android device error from the image